# Links in footer wont display inline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put some links in a footer next to each other, separated by the character "|". But I have a navbar whose styles interferes with the footer's links.

I need something like this :

[image]

This is my code (it doesn't display perfectly, but you get the gist):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    /*background-color: #e0eafc;*/
    background: linear-gradient( to right,#ff0000,#0000ff);
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.heading {
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.favcolorcontainer {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.colorpicker {
    border:none;
    background: white;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.favcolor {
    font-family: verdana;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.slideshow-container {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #a6a6a650;
}

.slide-name {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-number {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

.progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 3px;
}

.progress-tag {
    color: #DDDDDD;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.fill-html {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #FA3200;
    border-radius: 100px;
}


.fill-css {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #0000C8;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-js {
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #C80000;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-php {
    width: 3%;
    background-color: #00C832;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-rwpd {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #450099;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#return {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 35px;
  z-index: 99;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #0000d1;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 45px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  
}

#return:hover {
  background-color: #0101bb;
}

.progress-container {
    padding: 10px;
}

.header-logo {
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.header {
    background-color: #303030;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.desktop-nav {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.desktop-nav a {
    margin: 20px 30px 0 30px;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
}

.desktop-nav a:hover {
    color: #b4b4b4;
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
}

.desktop-nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu-button {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px;
    font-size:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white
}

.menu-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.copyright {
    color: #b4b4b4;
    font-size: 15px;

}
  
footer {
    background: #303030;
    padding: 25px 0;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.hyperlink {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #b4b4b4;
}

.hyperlink:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.hyperlink:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
  
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.recipe-container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.recipe-window {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    word-break: break-word;
    width: min-content;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.recipe-title {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

:root {
    color-scheme: dark;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://imgur.com/dFEoiLv">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="https://imgur.com/JntIYPP" width="150px" title="Aeron" alt="logo" class="header-logo">    
            <ul class="desktop-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="hyperlink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="hyperlink">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="hyperlink">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="demo.html" class="hyperlink">Demo</a></li>
            <li><a href="recipes.html" class="hyperlink">Recipes</a></li>
            <li><a href="progress.html" class="hyperlink">Progress</a></li>
            <li><a href="pcsetup.html" class="hyperlink">PC Setup Designer</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html" class="hyperlink">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><span class="menu-button" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <h1 class="heading">Welcome to Aeron</h1>
    <div style="height:100%"></div>
    <footer>
    <img src="./images/logo.png" width="150px" title="Aeron" alt="logo" class="footer-logo">
    <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2022 Aeron Corporation</p>
    <a href="">About Us</a>
    <p>|</p>
    <a href="">Policy</a>
    <p>|</p>
    <a href="">Contact Us</a>
    </footer>
    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="return" title="Return To Top">^</button>
    <script>
        let mybutton = document.getElementById("return");
        window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
        function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        mybutton.style.display = "block";
        } else {
        mybutton.style.display = "none";
        }
        }
        function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        }

          function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "25%";
          }
          
          function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
          }
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the links aren't displaying inline. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the links in a div with a class (I gave it `footer-links`) and give it the following styles:

```
.footer-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    /*background-color: #e0eafc;*/
    background: linear-gradient( to right,#ff0000,#0000ff);
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.heading {
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.favcolorcontainer {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.colorpicker {
    border:none;
    background: white;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.favcolor {
    font-family: verdana;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.slideshow-container {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #a6a6a650;
}

.slide-name {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-number {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

.progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 3px;
}

.progress-tag {
    color: #DDDDDD;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.fill-html {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #FA3200;
    border-radius: 100px;
}


.fill-css {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #0000C8;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-js {
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #C80000;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-php {
    width: 3%;
    background-color: #00C832;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.fill-rwpd {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #450099;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

#return {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 35px;
  z-index: 99;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #0000d1;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 45px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  
}

#return:hover {
  background-color: #0101bb;
}

.progress-container {
    padding: 10px;
}

.header-logo {
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.header {
    background-color: #303030;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.desktop-nav {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.desktop-nav a {
    margin: 20px 30px 0 30px;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
}

.desktop-nav a:hover {
    color: #b4b4b4;
    transition: 0.2s all ease;
}

.desktop-nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu-button {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px;
    font-size:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white
}

.menu-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.copyright {
    color: #b4b4b4;
    font-size: 15px;

}
  
footer {
    background: #303030;
    padding: 25px 0;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.hyperlink {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #b4b4b4;
}

.hyperlink:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.hyperlink:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
  
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.recipe-container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.recipe-window {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    word-break: break-word;
    width: min-content;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.recipe-title {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

:root {
    color-scheme: dark;
}

.footer-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.footer-links p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://imgur.com/dFEoiLv">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="https://imgur.com/JntIYPP" width="150px" title="Aeron" alt="logo" class="header-logo">    
            <ul class="desktop-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="hyperlink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="hyperlink">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="hyperlink">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="demo.html" class="hyperlink">Demo</a></li>
            <li><a href="recipes.html" class="hyperlink">Recipes</a></li>
            <li><a href="progress.html" class="hyperlink">Progress</a></li>
            <li><a href="pcsetup.html" class="hyperlink">PC Setup Designer</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html" class="hyperlink">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><span class="menu-button" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <h1 class="heading">Welcome to Aeron</h1>
    <div style="height:100%"></div>
    <footer>
    <img src="./images/logo.png" width="150px" title="Aeron" alt="logo" class="footer-logo">
    <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2022 Aeron Corporation</p>
    <div class="footer-links">
    <a href="">About Us</a>
    <p>|</p>
    <a href="">Policy</a>
    <p>|</p>
    <a href="">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
    </footer>
    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="return" title="Return To Top">^</button>
    <script>
        let mybutton = document.getElementById("return");
        window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
        function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        mybutton.style.display = "block";
        } else {
        mybutton.style.display = "none";
        }
        }
        function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        }

          function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "25%";
          }
          
          function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
          }
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also how can I reduce the vertical gap between the copyright tag and the links?

Comment: @BravoLima2k4 See my edit. Give `.footer-links p` a margin of 0.